# What's the proper way to call VBScript from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, vbscript, outlook

I'd like to be able to call a vbscript from Firefox that resides on network share. Thus it is visible to all my team members at work. Using:

```
<a href='file://///server/path/to/file.vbs'>run me</a>
```

What this script does is it grabs server side information through Samba from the client-side, and uses that information to bring up a MS Outlook new e-mail window with the HTML formatted server side (a Linux system) information filled in. I do not send the e-mail yet because I want to allow the teammate to make sure what they are about to send is correct. And we have to use Outlook. Unfortunately mailto: does not appear to allow any kind of HTML formatting, which is why I've turned to VBScript.

Seems to work in IE, although you get prompted before it allows you to run it. I guess that's OK for now. It's a little annoying having to make sure you're in IE to run it, especially for those of us who prefer not to use IE.

Right now all Firefox does is display the code contents in the browser.

I'm not even sure if I'm going about all this the right way, but from where I stand, I guess I'd like to be able to run it from Firefox. If not, I'll survive. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Even if it is, it's probably a security risk.

To launch the script, you'll have to run "wscript.exe file.vbs", but that's not allowed otherwise Viruses can exploit this easily.

Therefore, unless you want to use some browser exploit, this will not be possible.